# SOAP request to create sales order shipment partially

Tags: soap

I'm trying to create the sales order shipment partially in magento with the following request [1]. I get "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules". Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[1]

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
         <sessionId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
         <orderIncrementId>200006672</orderIncrementId>
         <itemsQty><orderItemIdQty><order_item_id>AG0102019</order_item_id><qty>1.0</qty></orderItemIdQty></itemsQty>
         <comment>Testing</comment>
         <email>1</email>
      </urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you are missing some tags that why u are getting this error

Comment: Is the structure of 'itemsQty' element correct? When I pass this element only I get this error.
<itemsQty><orderItemIdQty><order_item_id>AG0102019</order_item_id><qty>1.0</qty></orderItemIdQty></itemsQty>

Answer (score 1):

**Request Example SOAP V1**

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$orderIncrementId = '200000006';
$orderItemId = 3;
$qty = 5;
$itemsQty = array(
    $orderItemId => $qty,
    );

$result = $proxy->call(
    $session,
    'order_shipment.create',
    array(
        $orderIncrementId,
        $itemsQty
    )
);

var_dump ($result);
```

**Request Example SOAP V2**

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$itemsQty = array(
    array(
        'order_item_id' => 3,
        'qty' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'order_item_id' => 4,
        'qty' => 5
    ));

$result = $proxy->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId, '200000006', $itemsQty, 'shipment comment');
var_dump($result);
```

See more details [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.create.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already went through the doc. I'm not using the PHP client to send the request but need to send the request via SOAP UI with XML payload as I mentioned in the question. I hope this is the way to pass the 'itemsQty' element according to the documentation. But the back-end throws "Violation of encoding rules" exception in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The order_item_id is an integer type element and the passed value is string. So that the 'Violation of encoding rules' issue comes.

The request should be like this,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
         <orderIncrementId>200006672</orderIncrementId>
         <itemsQty>
                <urn:orderItemIdQty>
                    <order_item_id>13066</order_item_id>
                    <qty>1.0</qty>
                </urn:orderItemIdQty>
            </itemsQty>
      </urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```